# What's the proper/cleanest way to define a different context for actuator endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've seen several answers but Spring Boot properties and logic have changed a lot in that regard in the last versions.

Properties:

```
Boot 1.X: server.context-path + server.servlet-path + management.context-path
Boot 2.X: server.servlet.context-path + server.servlet.path + management.endpoints.web.base-path
```

Is there any way to configure this properties so the context for my app is `/myapp`, the context for REST controllers is `/myapp/api` and the context for actuators is `/myapp/actuators`?

Answer (score 0):

You could set `server.servlet.context-path` as a java option:

```
-Dserver.servlet.context-path=/myapp
```

we use spring boot 2.1, and this works for us.

Comment: But I fail to see how this solves the need I have, so actuators have different context-path

Comment: when you set server.servlet.context-path, it changes context for actuator endpoints aswell. do you want to have a different context for your rest api and actuator endpoints?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for the answer!